# Dynamically sort collection navigation property using linq

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am attempting to sort a collection based on a property.

So I do not know the property until runtime that I want to sort on.

The following works on the primary object but not any child objects

```
var prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TvRequests)).Find(sortProperty, tru

if (sortProperty.Contains('.'))
{
    // This is a navigation property currently not supported
    prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TvRequests)).Find("Title", true);
}
allRequests = sortOrder.Equals("asc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    ? allRequests.OrderBy(x => prop.GetValue(x)).ToList()
    : allRequests.OrderByDescending(x => prop.GetValue(x)).ToList();
```

So the `sortProperty` is passed into my method and is a string and can be something like `title` or `date` and it works. But if I attempt to access a child property of my `TvRequests` object it will not work e.g. `requestedUser.username`

This is a trimmed down version of my objects that I'm referring to in this question:

```
public class TvRequests
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(RequestedUserId))]
    public OmbiUser RequestedUser { get; set; }
}

public class OmbiUser
{
    public string Username;
}
```

My question is how would I be able to access any children properties like the above dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Use [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-2.1).

```
// Get the string name of the property here
string propertyName = "Title";
allRequests = sortOrder.Equals("asc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    ? allRequests.OrderBy(x => EF.Property<string>(x, propertyName)).ToList()
    : allRequests.OrderByDescending(x => EF.Property<string>(x, propertyName)).ToList();
```

Something along the lines may work (untested, but compiles)

```
// static for caching & performance 
static private MethodInfo efPropertyGenericMethod = typeof(EF).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("Property");

Expression SortBy<TEntity>(Type type, string propertyName)
{
    var xParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");

    // set T generic type here for EF.Property<T>
    var efPropertyMethod = efPropertyGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
    // Creates a Lambda
    Expression lambda = Expression.Lambda(
        // Calls a method. First parameter is null for static calls
        Expression.Call(null,
            efPropertyMethod, // our cosntructed generic Version of EF.Property<T>
            xParam, // Pass the x Parameter
            Expression.Constant(propertyName, typeof(string)) // the propertyName asconstant
        ),
        xParam
    );

    return lambda;
};
```

To be used as

```
allRequests.OrderBy(SortBy<TvRequests>(propertyType, propertyName))
```

Please note that that `SortBy` isn't called within the lambda. The below would be **wrong** (there's no `x =>` in the line above).

```
allRequests.OrderBy(x => SortBy<TvRequests>(propertyType, propertyName))
```

What it does? SortBy generates an expression tree equivalent of `x => EF.Property<T>(x, "MyPropertyName")`.

**Edit:**

Updated the method, so x is also passed to `EF.Property(x, propertyName)`

Comment: That looks about right, but the only problem being is that the type might not be a string, it could be a `DateTime`.

Comment: Then you'll have to dive into the hell of Expression Tree building :P

Comment: A starter point may be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries

Comment: Well to be fair, it would only be a `string` or a `DateTime`, there would be no other types... hmmm

Comment: Or try to build a static expression and modify (by changing property name and type) it via expression visitor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-modify-expression-trees

Comment: Well in that case a simple switch case may be sufficient (not as clean though)

Comment: You can give the ExpressionTree builder method above a try... *edit* missing the passing of x parameter to EF.Property...

Comment: Try the improved version of the ExpressionTree builder for sorting

Comment: In the `SortBy(x` what is `x`? since it's not part of the lambda? and I have nothing declared as `x`

Comment: Right, its because you don't need the reference but the type. And there was a bug anyways (the x parameters type was wrong). I'll update the answer. Removed the now obsolete x parameter

Comment: So i've updated the code now and it will no longer compile due to `The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: Mmmhh this ones harder. `TSource` is easy, its know at compile type (`TvRequests`), but `TKey` isn't (it would be `DateTime` or `string` in your case). One could build the generic with MakeGeneric, but then you would have to use reflection to apply `OrderBy`, which may be doable to, but the result of that may not be strong typed anymore and you'd be stuck too. You see, dynamic expression trees aren't that easy And `IQueryable` extensively uses Expression trees (but limits itself to compile type know information)

Comment: Well I know TKey before this and I'm able to work it out, so I can do something like a switch on it?

Comment: Yea, you can always do a switch. But you'll have code repetition

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this..

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public enum SortDirection { ASC,DESC}
    static LambdaExpression CreateExpression(Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
        Expression body = param;
        body = propertyName.Split('.')
            .Select(prop => body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, prop))
            .Last();
        return Expression.Lambda(body, param);
    }
    public static IQueryable<T> SortBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,string expressionField,SortDirection sortDirection = SortDirection.ASC)
    {
        var lambdaExpression = CreateExpression(typeof(T), expressionField) as dynamic;
        return sortDirection == SortDirection.ASC ? Queryable.OrderBy(source,lambdaExpression) : Queryable.OrderByDescending(source, lambdaExpression);
    }

}
```

types

```
public class TvRequests
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public OmbiUser RequestedUser { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class OmbiUser
{
    public string Username;
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

using

```
    List<TvRequests> reqList = new List<TvRequests>();
    reqList.Add(new TvRequests {
        Title = "A",
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
        RequestedUser = new OmbiUser
        {
            Username = "A",
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
        }
    });
    reqList.Add(new TvRequests
    {
        Title = "C",
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        RequestedUser = new OmbiUser
        {
            Username = "C",
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
        }
    });
    reqList.Add(new TvRequests
    {
        Title = "B",
        Date = DateTime.Now,
        RequestedUser = new OmbiUser
        {
            Username = "B",
            Date = DateTime.Now
        }
    });
    foreach (var item in reqList.AsQueryable().SortBy("Date", SortDirection.DESC))
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Title);
    foreach (var item in reqList.AsQueryable().SortBy("RequestedUser.Date"))
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Title);
    foreach (var item in reqList.AsQueryable().SortBy("RequestedUser.UserName",SortDirection.DESC))
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Title);
```